# Easiest way to get column width/length from a ResultSet - must I iterate though?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I need to get the column width/length from a `ResultSet/ResultSetMetaData` knowing only its name? I could create a map of names to indexes and get it that way, but is there another way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the columns, types and lots more from ResultSetMetaData.

You can't get the number of rows returned without iterating through it.

Comment: You need to know the index. Just realised there is a findColumn(columnName) method in ResultSet. Gahh... I've been iterating through and matching.

Comment: No, you can get by column name, as you've just said.  I don't know what "need the index" means.